# Notifying a task from multiple other tasks without extra work

Tags: concurrency, rust, async-await, channel

My application is futures-based with async/await, and has the following structure within one of its components:

1. a "manager", which is responsible for starting/stopping/restarting "workers", based both on external input and on the current state of "workers";
2. a dynamic set of "workers", which perform some continuous work, but may fail or be stopped externally.

A worker is just a spawned [task](https://docs.rs/async-std/1.4.0/async_std/task/index.html) which does some I/O work. Internally it is a loop which is intended to be infinite, but it may exit early due to errors or other reasons, and in this case the worker must be restarted from scratch by the manager.

The manager is implemented as a loop which awaits on several channels, including one returned by [`async_std::stream::interval`](https://docs.rs/async-std/1.4.0/async_std/stream/fn.interval.html), which essentially makes the manager into a poller - and indeed, I need this because I do need to poll some `Mutex`-protected external state. Based on this state, the manager, among everything else, creates or destroys its workers.

Additionally, the manager stores a set of [`async_std::task::JoinHandle`](https://docs.rs/async-std/1.4.0/async_std/task/struct.JoinHandle.html)s representing live workers, and it uses these handles to check whether any workers has exited, restarting them if so. (BTW, I do this currently using `select(handle, future::ready())`, which is totally suboptimal because it relies on the `select` implementation detail, specifically that it polls the left future first. I couldn't find a better way of doing it; something like [`race()`](https://docs.rs/async-std/1.4.0/async_std/prelude/trait.FutureExt.html#method.race) would make more sense, but `race()` consumes both futures, which won't work for me because I don't want to lose the `JoinHandle` if it is not ready. This is a matter for another question, though.)

You can see that in this design workers can only be restarted when the next poll "tick" in the manager occurs. However, I don't want to use a too small interval for polling, because in most cases polling just wastes CPU cycles. Large intervals, however, can delay restarting a failed/canceled worker by too much, leading to undesired latencies. Therefore, I though I'd set up another channel of `()`s back from each worker to the manager, which I'd add to the main manager loop, so when a worker stops due to an error or otherwise, it will first send a message to its channel, resulting in the manager being woken up earlier than the next poll in order to restart the worker right away.

Unfortunately, with any kinds of channels this might result in *more* polls than needed, in case two or more workers stop at approximately the same time (which due to the nature of my application, is somewhat likely to happen). In such case it would make sense to only run the manager loop once, handling all of the stopped workers, but with channels it will necessarily result in the number of polls equal to the number of stopped workers, even if additional polls don't do anything.

Therefore, my question is: how do I notify the manager from its workers that they are finished, without resulting in extra polls in the manager? I've tried the following things:

1. As explained above, regular unbounded channels just won't work.
2. I thought that maybe bounded channels *could* work - if I used a channel with capacity 0, and there was a way to try and send a message into it but just drop the message if the channel is full (like the [`offer()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#offer(E)) method on Java's `BlockingQueue`), this seemingly would solve the problem. Unfortunately, the channels API, while providing such a method (`try_send()` seems to be like it), also has this property of having capacity larger than or equal to the number of senders, which means it can't really be used for such notifications.
3. Some kind of atomic or a mutex-protected boolean flag also *look* as if it could work, but there is no atomic or mutex API which would provide a future to wait on, and would also require polling.
4. Restructure the manager implementation to include `JoinHandle`s into the main `select` somehow. It might do the trick, but it would result in large refactoring which I'm unwilling to make at this point. If there is a way to do what I want without this refactoring, I'd like to use that first.
5. I guess some kind of combination of atomics and channels might work, something like setting an atomic flag and sending a message, and then skipping any extra notifications in the manager based on the flag (which is flipped back to off after processing one notification), but this also seems like a complex approach, and I wonder if anything simpler is possible.

Comment: What's wrong with [`futures::future::select_all`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.1/futures/future/fn.select_all.html)?

Comment: Are you using a custom executor?

Comment: @edwardw sorry, I don't understand how I'd apply `select_all` here. Any kind of select, really. Would be great if you could provide an example :)

Comment: @PeterHall no, just the default async_std executor.

Comment: @edwardw oh, I see - this might be related to my 4th point, about redesigning the architecture to include selecting on `JoinHandle`s. As I said, I'd prefer to avoid that if I can.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the [`FuturesUnordered`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3/futures/stream/struct.FuturesUnordered.html) type from the `futures` crate. This collection allows you to push many futures of the same type into a collection and wait for any one of them to complete at once.

It implements `Stream`, so if you import [`StreamExt`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html), you can use `unordered.next()` to obtain a future that completes once any future in the collection completes.

If you also need to wait for a timeout or mutex etc., you can use [`select`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.1/futures/future/fn.select.html) to create a future that completes once either the timeout or one of the join handles completes. The future returned by `next()` implements `Unpin`, so it is usable with `select` without problems.

Comment: Yeah, this also falls under the 4th point, I think, because I will need to restructure the code significantly to use `FuturesUnordered`. But it is indeed a proper option; if nothing better comes up I guess that would be my only choice :)